# Android LoaderCallback not refresh

Tags: android, loader, fragment

I'm using `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>` in my `FragmentActivity`.

I invoke in `onResume()`:
`getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, loader);`

I invoke in `onCreate()`:

```
loader = new ApplicationLoader();
getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, loader);
```

Finally I have:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
       // Deleting row from database
    }
});
```

But my list does not refresh its items.

Only way to work is invoke:

```
loader = new ApplicationLoader();
getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, loader);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having a similar problem. I had forgotten to call:

```
getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
```

After insert, update, and delete. Also, **do not close any cursors.** The loader does that for you.

Comment: The loaders don't close the cursor automatically. You have to call [`changeCursor(null)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/CursorAdapter.html#changeCursor(android.database.Cursor)) to close the cursor.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to answer to my question. It's exactly.

Comment: @LaiVung "The loader will release the data once it knows the application is no longer using it. For example, if the data is a cursor from a CursorLoader, you should not call close() on it yourself. If the cursor is being placed in a CursorAdapter, you should use the swapCursor() method so that the old Cursor is not closed."  -http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html